# Is the Riemann sphere really just the entire complex plane where you add a "single point" at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-sphere

It's well known that the [Riemann Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) is defined as the complex plane plus a point at infinity.

Question: Is the point at infinity really a single point, or is it a circle that has dimension 0?

If we make the replacement $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ then we can say that the origin represents the point at infinity.  But this is really not accurate, since the origin under this mapping got deleted, and it's necessary to treat *every possible angle of approach* as a distinct path.  This corresponds to the fact that starting from any finite part of the complex plane, there are an infinite number of ways to move in a straight line off to infinity. [1]

The problem of treating infinity as a single point becomes apparent when we take some polynomial which is well defined everywhere in the entire complex plane, and only has a single singularity at infinity, and make the transformation

$$z \to \frac{1}{z}$$

Then what happens is our polynomial just got turned into a rational function that has poles which are all over the complex plane, and whereas the polynomial can approach infinity from any direction and it's only singularity is at the point at infinity, when we take $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ the singularity at infinity disappears and is replaced by poles which are not all at the same point.

This makes perfect sense (to me) when the point at infinity is a circle with dimension 0.  Although the concept of "a circle with dimension 0" is something I just made up, and which is not well defined, my intuition tells me that there is a topological distinction between a single point and a circle with dimension 0.  Is there any such concept as a circle with dimension 0, or is that a bad way of thinking about this?

I want a circle with dimension 0 to be the point of tangency between two spheres that only touch at a single point.  In other words, its not just a single point because it has an extra dimension to play around with, but the intersection just looks like a single point, if that makes sense.

This issue about the difference between the Riemann sphere and the standard projective geometry approach has been bothering me for over 10 years, and any help clarifying my confusion here is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

[1] Modern Anaylysis, Whittaker & Watson, 4th edition, 5.62 The "point at infinity"

Comment: There is no "extra dimension to play around with" for a circle of radius $0.$

Comment: Every point in the plane has a pencil of lines through it. What you're talking about would seem to be just that pencil of lines.

Comment: Another way to think of the Riemann sphere is: the complex projective line.  Maybe that will help you understand it better, and see why $\infty$ is just a point.  In the real projective plane there is, indeed a whole "line at infinity".  But of course the complex multiplication is not defined on that.

Comment: Surely polynomials don't have an essential singularity at infinity?

Comment: @ancientmathematician quoting from the reference I cited "$f(z)$ is said to have an *essential singularity* at infinity, if $\phi(z^{\prime})$ has an essential singularity at the point $z^{\prime}=0$"  In this quote $\phi(z^{\prime})$ refers to the transformation $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ applied to the function $f(z)$.

Comment: @GEdgar The idea of a complex projective line might be the concept I am looking for.  Thanks.  I need to research that more carefully, but it does ring a bell.  I am also confused about an intuitive way to understand complex projective lines, but that is a different question! =)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I disagree with your statement "Every point in the plane has a pencil of lines through it".  Instead I would phrase this as "every plane has a pencil of lines through every point". I was under the impression that a point is just a point, and that it doesn't have any extra information it carries around with it, at least from a topological perspective.  So the lines are not in the point, they are in the plane, because the point has no extra dimensions to play with.

Comment: Do you mean $f(\frac{1}{z})$? It certainly doesn't have an essential singularity.

Comment: I urge you to take seriously @GEdgar's comment. $\mathbb{C}$ is a (complex) line; we generalise, and look at the projective line $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$; we ask what this looks like in **real terms** and lo and behold it is a sphere: the points of $\mathbb{C}$ correspond to the points of the sphere apart from the north pole, the point $\infty$ corresponds to the north pole.

Comment: @ancientmathematician here is a link to google books with the reference I was quoting from.  I meant what they meant.  I think I misused "essential singularity" in what I wrote previously and am going to edit the question to remove the word "essential" https://books.google.com/books?id=ULVdGZmi9VcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Did you see already the concept of manifold? The circle is a manifold because it is covered by two real intervals that we glue together. It is the same for the Riemann sphere: it is covered by two open complex disks $|z|<2$ that we glue through $z\to 1/z$ (for $1/2<|z|<2$). So $\infty$ is just the $0$ of the second disk. $f$ is meromorphic on the Riemann sphere iff both $f(z),f(1/z)$ are meromorphic on $|z|<2$.

Comment: @MattCalhoun, no need for that, the book is still on my shelves, and there's lots of good stuff in it - but it is a bit old-fashioned in how it treats $\infty$ - the background of its original audience would have had a lot of background and intuition in geometry (affine and projective, real and complex) that we don't perhaps share.

Comment: I wish you'd show us a concrete example, perhaps looking at the polynomial $z^2-1$ - how does it get "turned into a rational function that has poles all over the plane". All the singularity of $f(\frac{1}{z})$ is at $0$, if you meant $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ what's the relevance of that?

Comment: @ancientmathematician That is one of my favorite books =) So after trying to find an example for your question, I reached the conclusion that polynomials under the transformation $z \to 1/z$ behave as you stated, in other words, the singularities are all at zero when you make this transformation to a polynomial.  So my question contained this mistake, which kind of invalidates most of the question.  I still think there is something weird about the transformation $z \to 1/z$, but it's not what I said in my question, and I need to come up with another way to investigate the weird part.

Comment: I think the reason I made this mistake without being careful and checking examples is because I was thinking of taking a Laurent expansion to a function that has both zero's and poles, and doing $z \to 1/z$ to it.  Before making any more assertions about this topic, or asking further questions, I clearly need to pay closer attention to the formula's and calculate more things explicitly.

Comment: @reuns yes I was thinking about the double cover of the sphere last night before I saw your comment.  Something like "if we take a single point and add it to the complex plane, it becomes a sphere which can be covered by two open complex discs"  The problem I am worrying about is when you do $z \to 1/z$ that $i \to 1/i = -i$ which means left and right hand of the complex plane got swapped, so doing $z \to 1/z$ is sort of like implicitly taking the complex conjugate of every point in the complex plane.  I'm not sure where to go with this concern at this time tho.

Comment: @reuns (cont.) Glueing together two discs into a sphere, intuitively for me, means using a circle to glue them together around the equator of the sphere.  Glueing two discs together into a sphere using a single point, intuitively for me, means taking both discs, bending them into half-spheres, and then sticking the top of each half-sphere together so it's touches at a single point.  I am trying to wrap my head around glueing two discs together with a single point into a sphere instead of into two halves of a sphere touching at a single point.

Comment: The $i$ of the first disk is not the same as the $i$ of the second disk. Call them $(i,1),(i,2)$, two different points of the Riemann sphere, then the gluing is saying that $(z,1)=(1/z,2)$ for $1/2<|z|<2$ (we glue along an annulus to get everywhere some local bihoolomorphism to a complex disk, so that analyticity/meromorphicity makes sense). Then the point at infinity is just $(0,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I have never really thought of the Riemann Sphere as anything more than a abstract tool. It helps us better understand why particular complex functions behave the way they do. Take for example, LFTs (linear fractional transformations). Now it is a well known theorem that LFTs map "circles and lines" to "circles and lines". However this feels cumbersome and there is a certain beauty lost in trying to distinguish lines from circles, or in attempting to figure which lines go to which circles or which lines and visa-versa. However, a particular clarity is found when LFTs are placed on the Riemann Sphere; and we suddenly realize that the statement was in error, really LFTs map circles to circles, that's it. There are no lines on the Riemann Sphere; lines in the complex plane are simply the special case of circles on the Riemann Sphere that happen to go through $\infty$. Now doesn't that sound nice to say, "LFTs map circles to circles".

This kind of abstract extension of a space "to complete it" is done all the time. A similar example would be Elliptic Curve Geometry. Without going into the nuances, assume for a moment that their exist curves (symmetric about the x-axis) with the property that given any two points on the curve and the tangent line between them, then there is guaranteed to exist a third point on the curve that passes through the tangent line. We can then define an algebraic "addition" on the curve, by $A+B=C$ if $C$ is the reflective point across the x-axis of the third point that intersects the tangent line between $A$ and $B$. This works everywhere, except one small caveat. What happens if $A$ and $B$ are exactly vertical from each other, then algebraically they are apparently $A$ and $-A$, opposites of each other. But there is no third point that passes through a vertical line on an Elliptic Curve. So how do we resolve that in our mind? The geometry shows there is no third point, yet logically, $A+(-A)$ should be $0$. The solution is that $0$ is really the point at $\infty$, and so on an Elliptic Curve, the abstraction that $A+\infty=\infty+A = A$ for any $A$, makes sense geometrically; thus $\infty$ is the zero of the abstract group.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that "The solution is that 0 is really the point at ∞, and so on an Elliptic Curve".  This is not accurate because for an elliptic curve in a projective plane, there is not a single point at infinity, but an entire circle at infinity.  This distinction is what I was trying to get at in my question.  However I do appreciate when you stated "I have never really thought of the Riemann Sphere as anything more than a abstract tool."  I think my confusion stems from thinking of the Riemann sphere as a "perfect sphere", which is not a well defined concept.

Comment: For an Elliptic Curve the "addition operation of points on that curve using tangent lines" has an object called zero such that for all points in the group, $0+P=P+0=P$ (this is known as the Group of the Elliptic Curve, the zero is referred to as the identity of the Group). Visually, $0$ is the third point of a vertical line that passes through the Elliptic Curve, hence "the zero of Elliptic Curve addition" is visually/geometrically the point at infinity in the plane. I am simply pointing out how unintuitive infinity can be abstractly used.

Comment: Hmm.  I thought an elliptic curve was in a complex projective space, which is distinct from the Riemann sphere.  The distinction is that two parallel lines in a complex projective plane intersect at a single point at infinity, but two other parallel lines at a *different angle* intersect at a *different* point at infinity, because in a complex projective space there is a projective line at infinity, not just a single point.