# How should I glue together the sides of the complex plane when adding a "single point" at infinity?

Tags: general-topology, riemann-sphere

If we construct the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) by taking a single point at infinity and adding it to the complex plane, then if I start with the point
$$z = 1 + i$$
in the finite part of the complex plane, and then push that point off to the top right and to infinity on a straight line at a 45 degree angle, then which side of the finite part of the complex plane does that point come back from?  Is it the bottom left at a 45 degree angle?  I thought that was topologically the projective plane.  Is there some kind of very subtle distinction here related to the metric, or do we need to use 8 arrows instead of 4 in the fundamental rectangle?  Even so, I still can't see which side a point pushed off to the top right would come back from if its not the bottom left(except maybe it comes back from the top right going the other way, but I find that very confusing, although conceptually possible).

In order to glue together the sides of the complex plane into a projective plane, you glue the top to the bottom like a mobius strip, and the left and the right like a mobius strip.

[image]

If the Riemann sphere is topologically distinct from a projective plane, then how can this distinction be represented in terms of gluing together the sides of a fundamental rectangle as in the picture above?

Thanks!

(NOTE:  I recently asked this question [Is the Riemann sphere really just the entire complex plane where you add a "single point" at infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057880/is-the-riemann-sphere-really-just-the-entire-complex-plane-where-you-add-a-sing?noredirect=1#comment8382762_4057880) and feel like the confusion I had was resolved by a comment, and now I have a different question.)

Comment: You talk about the "sides" of the complex plane, but then your picture shows the sides of a finite square. The complex plane is not a finite square.

Comment: You also talk about the "finite part" of the complex plane, as if there were any other part. What part of the complex plane is not in the "finite part"?

Comment: @LeeMosher these are excellent questions!  I think whats going on is I am confused about something.  Maybe instead of sides of the complex plane, what I have in mind are the 4 distinct regions around the origin where the signs of both x and y are fixed.  As for what "the finite part" means, what I had in mind was since we just added a point "at infinity", that everything besides that point is the "finite part".  I feel obligated to treat the point at infinity we just added in a special way and am confused about what that way is.   Your comments are very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topologically, the Riemann sphere is the [one point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of the complex plane, which is not usually constructed via a gluing procedure. It is defined as $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$ where the open sets are either ordinary open subsets of $\mathbb C$ or sets containing $\infty$ whose complement is compact in $\mathbb C$ (that is, $\infty$ and all of $\mathbb C$ except a closed, bounded portion). This means that the Riemann sphere is topologically equivalent to the standard $2$-sphere $S^2$, not the projective plane.

Using gluing to construct the Riemann sphere is not natural because a gluing procedure involves identifying edges of polygons, but the complex plane does not have edges--it is not compact. There are many ways you could add edges to the complex plane and then construct a sphere via gluing, but none of them extend the geometry of the complex plane naturally because instead of adding just one point, you have to add a whole system of edges.

For example: find a homeomorphism from the complex plane to the interior of square, and treat the edges of that square as the "edges" of the complex plane. Then you could label the edges $a$, $a^{-1}$, $b$, $b^{-1}$. Gluing them together would result in a sphere, but it would not extend the geometry of the complex plane in the way you describe (i.e., pushing a point to the top right, and having it reappear on the bottom left).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me!  I think it's starting to all click together.  I am thinking about the idea of gluing a fundamental rectangle too literally, and the geometric intuition I have about space is breaking down because I am applying the idea of "glueing" to a place where it's not appropriate and doesn't work.

Comment: If the Riemann sphere is topologically equivalent to the standard 2-sphere, would it be a terrible abuse of terminology to think of the point at infinity that got added to the complex plane to transform it into Riemann sphere as "kind of like the point of tangency of two spheres which only touch at a single point"?

Comment: Your comment makes me wonder if there is another misunderstanding. The 2 in "2-sphere" refers to the dimension of the sphere, not the number of spheres. It is just one sphere, and $\infty$ is one point in it.

Comment: That was a misunderstanding, whoops *sigh.  I have never been able to truly grok complex projective lines or spaces.  I think from all the comments I found the answers I needed to continue researching everything.  I can't get past the feeling that there is something weird about adding a point at infinity and just holding your nose and not worrying about which quadrant you come back from if you move along a straight line to the point at infinity, but I could accept that this is just how it is, I just need to figure it out for myself by researching more.  Thanks!

Comment: The way I am thinking of it now is, starting from the set of 5 elements 1,-1, i, -i, 0.  I can add one more element $\infty$, and now i have 6 points which form the ends of 3d system of mutually ortogonal coordinate axis. And all that happened was a single point was added. Lmk if this also contains a misunderstanding pls =) i think i almost get it! And rereading this answer was very helpful

Comment: I think there is still a misunderstanding. The Riemann sphere is still 2 dimensional in the same sense that a balloon, though it exists in three dimensions, has only a two dimensional surface. Moreover, to talk about orthogonality, we need to have a dot product (this is how orthogonality is defined). Though $\mathbb C$ has a dot product, once we add infinity, there is no way to define the dot product in a consistent way.

Comment: You are right about dot product.  I am visualizing the complex plane as embedded in a 3d space, which is not really an accurate picture.  You said "The Riemann sphere is still 2 dimensional", but I think there is more going on here.  The distinction between a 2d surface and the complex plane is that the complex plane comes with two distinct implicit ambiguities: the meaning of $i,-i$, and a choice of right hand or left hand rule.  The complex plane also comes with an implicit definition of complex conjugate since its not just a plane.  You can have a left hand rule and not swap $i,-i$ etc...

Comment: (cont..) I feel like these double ambiguities can be resolved by visualizing the complex plane as embedded in a 3d space, and then making a choice about what $i,-i$ means, and if you have a right hand or left hand rule, corresponds to putting a point at infinity either above or below the embedded complex plane, because these 2 ambiguities are logically connected in a subtle and weird way I am trying to wrap my head around.  Does my objection have a basis in the underlying theory here or not?  Thank you so much for your time btw, much appreciated =)

Comment: I think what you are saying is reasonable, but it is also reasonable and arguably more helpful to think of the Riemann sphere as just a sphere. Imagine a sphere that barely fits inside a cube. The cube touches the sphere at six points. These six points are $0$, $\infty$, $1$, $-1$, $i$, and $-i$, where $0$ is opposite $\infty$, $1$ is opposite $-1$, and $i$ is opposite $-i$. (Now throw away the cube it has no real meaning, just a convenient way to select six points).

Comment: I disagree when you say its "arguably more helpful to think of the Riemann sphere as just a sphere" what is the difference between a vector and the imaginary number $i$?  I argue that the $i$ comes with a group structure of size 4, and the only groups of size 4 are group with 4 commuting elements and the cyclic group of size 4.  There is a difference between $i$ and a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in that by definition $i^{-1}=-i$, but no such operation exists for a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  This distinction is lost by thinking its a regular sphere imo. See https://xkcd.com/2028/ =)

Comment: (cont...) furthermore, the significance of the identity $i^{-1}=-i$ is very fundamental, imo, because it relates how 0 plays a special role in the field of real numbers when considered as a group under the operations of addition and multiplication.  Under multiplication we must remove 0, but the group structure is preserved when $i^{-1}=-i$ because $i + (-i) = 0$, in other words, when $\mathbb{R}$ is extended by adding $i$, $i$ is it's own multiplicative inverse, as well as it's own additive inverse.  At least, this is my current intuition as I continue to study and get feedback.

Comment: All this algebra is nice, but it goes out the window when considering the RIemann sphere. Adding $\infty$ destroys the field structure of the complex numbers (though your subgroup $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ remains). All that is left are the analytic (smooth) structure of the complex numbers. It is nice because analytically, all points of the complex plane have the same properties, and the Riemann sphere adds $\infty$ which also has the same properties. This means it is useful for studying e.g., rational functions, showing that singularities at finite points or $\infty$ are all really the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120930/discussion-between-alex-s-and-matt-calhoun).

Answer (score 1):

You could think of the complex plane as the interior of the closed disk in the plane. If we then squeeze the boundary circle to a point (the point at infinity ) we get the Riemann sphere. So we do have a circle at infinity (all directions) but we identify all directions to one "infinity" point.

We could put a compatible metric on the disk defined by $d(z,w)  = |f(z)-f(w)|$ where $z,w$ lie in the interior and $f(z)=\frac{z}{1-|z|} \in \Bbb C$ and $d(z, \infty) = \frac{1}{1-|z|}$. Then a sequence that converges to the boundary in the disk becomes a sequence converging to $\infty$ as it ought.